# Log Analytics :: Find Resources with no activities for the last 90 days

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I was reading [this blog](https://yourazurecoach.com/2019/12/05/cut-azure-costs-by-automatically-removing-inactive-resource-groups/) and I found out that there is a query that could return me all Resource Groups with the relative activities for the last 90 days:

```
AzureActivity
| where CategoryValue == "Administrative"
| where EventSubmissionTimestamp > ago(90d)
| summarize activityCount = count() by ResourceGroup
| order by activityCount asc
```

This is very useful but I would like to have the same but with the activities for each Resource instead of the Resource Group. So I tried this:

```
AzureActivity
| where CategoryValue == "Administrative"
| where EventSubmissionTimestamp > ago(90d)
| summarize activityCount = count() by Properties.Resource
| order by activityCount asc
```

but it's not working.

I know that the resource name is under Properties but I cannot project it.

Comment: when you write *"it's not working"* it doesn't provide the reader required information of what's not working, i.e. the actual error message you're encountering. if you do that, it may help readers help you. my *guess* is that you need to cast `Properties.Resource` to `string`, as you can't aggregate by a `dynamic` value. i.e.: `| summarize activityCount = count() by tostring(Properties.Resource)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I check resources activity with below KQL query:

```
AzureActivity
| where CategoryValue == "Administrative"
| where TimeGenerated > ago(90d)
| summarize activityCount = count() by Resource
| order by activityCount asc
```

**`Output:`**

[image]